# Laravel 4.1 - Detect app environment

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1 
I have a local version of my project `dev` and two version on remote server such as `beta`and `production`

How can I detect my app environment : `beta` , `production` or `dev` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `bootstrap/start.php` file. In this file you should find `detectEnvironment` call:

```
<?php
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
     'production' => array('production-machine-name'),
     'beta'  => array('beta-machine-name'),
     'dev'   => array('dev-machine-name'),
));
```

Check Laravel documentation regarding environment for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SERVER hostname (like I usually do) if hostnames are similar:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.dev'))) ? 'development' : 'production';
});
```

Code will work for .dev in domain but it can be easily changed to your needs.